# Dict keyword can't be an expression. How to convert a variable from object to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to convert a variable from object to integer

```
mapper = dict('А Б' = 0 , 'Г Д' = 1)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

'А Б' , 'Г Д' - russian letters. 
What is correct way to convert a variable from object to integer?
Both python 3.5 or 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a a dict literal instead:

```
mapper = {'А Б': 0, 'Г Д': 1}
```

The error was absolutely right.  You can't do `'foo' = 4` on its own, and you can't do it in a function call.